# We have $f_n(a_n)=1$ and $(\forall k> n)(f_n(a_{k})=0)$ in a metric space and all $f_n$ are uniformly continuous. Can $(a_n)$ be convergent?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

$(a_n)$ is a sequence in the metric space $(X,d)$.

For each $n\in \Bbb N$, $f_n:X\to [0,1]$ is a uniformly continuous function and
$$f_n(a_n)=1$$
and
$$(\forall k> n)(f_n(a_{k})=0)$$

Can $(a_n)$ be convergent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it can. Try $X=[0,1]$, $a_n=2^{-n}$ and $f_n(x)=g(2^{n+1}x)$ with $g(x)=\max\{0,\min\{x-1,1\}\}$. Then $f_n(2^{-k})=0$ if $k\geqslant n+1$ and $f_n(2^{-k})=1$ if $k\leqslant n$.

Comment: You probably want to change $f_n$ a bit so it would be a function into $[0,1]$.

Comment: @Asaf Indeed I do. Thanks.